# Adding Section To The Structure But Not The Document

Tags: sectioning

To help organize my document and jump around when writing, I like using section titles. But I don't want these sections to actually appear at all in the document once compiled (meaning no number, no text, no addition to the table of contents). Is there a command to do this?

Comment: well assuming that you do the jumping with bookmarks, you could use the bookmark package to add them where you want.

Comment: The `comment` package? `\begin{comment} \section{XYZ} .... \end{comment}` and section XYZ and what follows will not be typeset.

Comment: @Peter Wilson This gets me halfway there in that the section is not showing up in the document, but unfortunately it also eliminates the "sections" on the structure portion of LaTeX when I am creating the document

Comment: @EDS What is the "structure" portion?

Comment: For me, my screen is divided into three parts-- the right-most portion is the pdf view of the document, the middle portion is the .tex file that I am writing, and the left-most portion is labeled structure. That is where I see the various chapters, sections, sub sections, etc. in my document.